# Passing a result set between SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 sql statements, 
the first one will generate 1 column ID# and about 2000 rows,

ex:

```
select  Field1
  from xyz  
 where xxxx ='0' 
 group by Field1 
 order by field1 asc 
OFFSET 1 ROWS
```

I want to take the value of each row and do another select statement with this ID#

```
select lId 
  from xyz 
 where b ='0' 
   and field1 = 'here the value from the first statement ' 
 order by lId ASC
```

which will always produce 1 column and 2 rows , I want to take these two rows and insert the first in an update statement and the second in the where clause of that update stamen 
then run a delete statement to delete the second row

```
update abc 
   set luid = 'first value' 
 where lUsId = 'second value'

delete 
  from xyz 
 where lId ='<second value>'
```

Please assist me

Comment: Try inserting into a temp table and use the temp table in your next query.

Comment: As @JacobH mentioned, this sounds very much like a temp table kind of scenario. For the purpose of asking a question which will get you a good response, please following the advice in this link: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: No I do not want to insert into any temp table
I just want to loop through the result sets between tables ..

Comment: Please post DDL, sample data and desired results when asking this kind of question.  It's awefully vague.  In general is sounds like you might be thinking of a cursor.  But looping through the rows with a cursor is not the best way to solve this kind of problem.  You want to use a set-based approach.

Comment: Why would you not want to use a temp table? This sounds like a very programmatic way of going about this when a set-based method would be _much_ more efficient and less error-prone. Sample data would be very helpful to see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: And which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Are you updating one table (xyz) based on SELECT values from that same table (xyz) and then DELETing from another table (abc) based on a different column of of the SELECT from xyz?

Comment: I will add sample data as requested,  though i am not sure how to use the set based approach to loop through the result set data from the first select.